# How do CMake placeholders work?

Tags: cmake

Inside the support libraries for CMake, you'll see command definitions that look like this:

```
 set(CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_ASM${ASM_DIALECT}_COMPILER> <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -o <OBJECT> -c <SOURCE>")
```

(from `/usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeASMInformation.cmake` in my install for example)

The objects of interest here to me are the [placeholders (phrase obtained here)](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/677c091b8140a0655f512b8283c5b120fbd0f99c?view=parallel): `<DEFINES>` `<INCLUDES>` `<FLAGS>`; I'm trying to figure out how they interact with the rest of CMake.

Given that I was able to pass flags to my assembler by setting `CMAKE_ASM-ATT_FLAGS`, I had sort of thought that there might be some magic mapping a placeholder to a variable name... but setting `CMAKE_ASM-ATT_INCLUDES` didn't seem to do anything.

So how would `<INCLUDES>` be populated here? Can it be filled in a target-specific manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a little magic in origin of placeholders:

- <DEFINES> is filled by [add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_definitions.html), `target_compile_definitions` commands and corresponded properties,
- <INCLUDES> is filled by [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/include_directories.html), `target_include_directories` and so,
- <FLAGS> is filled by `add_compile_options`, `target_compile_options` and so plus *CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS* variable and its configuration-specific pair,
- <SOURCE> are source files and
- <OBJECT> are corresponded objects.

That is, everything which affects building of C/C++ programs affects (after being language-adapted) on library/executables on other languages.