# CMake toolchain expressions

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I am trying to write a Toolchain file for a custom compiler and I am stuck at the options of the tools. I actually need a variation of the output filename to be added to a parameter in `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` variable.

I found random examples on the internet on how to include some expressions, like `<TARGET>` and `<OBJECTS>` but https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html avoids to explain them properly. **What are those?** Some look like variables, some like Generator expressions (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html ) , some like CMake properties.

But where are the valid ones listed? And which string operations can I do with them?

Answer (score 0):

They are placeholders. They don't necessarily correspond to any variable or property. They are specific to rules like `CMAKE_<LANG>_LINK_EXECUTABLE`.

I couldn't find any documentation about them, but there's some information in the [source](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/36d35d4e/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake#L231) for CXX rules.

Sources:

- [How do CMake placeholders work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44958411)
- [`cmRulePlaceholderExpander::ExpandVariable`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/36d35d4e/Source/cmRulePlaceholderExpander.cxx#L22)
- [Example of setting up `RuleVariables` from the source](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/36d35d4e/Source/cmMakefileExecutableTargetGenerator.cxx#L527)